# vb.net 2022 PrintDocument in Windows 10 and Windows 11

Tags: vb.net, windows-10, windows-11, printdocument

```
 Private Sub PrintDocument2_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument2.PrintPage

        Dim adjustToA4 As New Rectangle(0, 0, e.PageBounds.Width, e.PageBounds.Height)
        Dim adjustDGVtoA4 As New Rectangle(5, 300, e.PageBounds.Width - 10, e.PageBounds.Height - 600)

        Dim dm As New Bitmap(Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height)
        Panel1.DrawToBitmap(dm, New Rectangle(0, 0, Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height))
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(dm, adjustToA4)

        Dim dgv As New Bitmap(DataGridView1.Width, DataGridView1.Height)
        DataGridView1.DrawToBitmap(dgv, New Rectangle(0, 0, DataGridView1.Width, DataGridView1.Height))
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(dgv, adjustDGVtoA4)

    End Sub
```

I have done coding in vb.net 2022 in windows 10 platform... and build setup in windows 10.. and I run the setup in windows 11.. and the app runs fine... but when I print the document, it doesn't run like which has been printed in the windows 10 platform.. do you have any suggestions..

note: I have changed the coding on "Dim adjustDGVtoA4 As New Rectangle(60, 300, e.PageBounds.Width - 120, e.PageBounds.Height - 600) " and print in windows 11, it is ok... but when I print in windows 10, it is not ok.

thank you...

"translation to english"

[image: Print in Windows 10]
Print in Windows 10 before editing code...

[image: Print in Windows 11]
Print in Windows 11 before editing code...

[image: Print in Windows 10 back]
Print in Windows 10, after editing code

Answer (score 0):

```
 Private Sub PrintDocument2_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument2.PrintPage

    If Environment.OSVersion.Version.Build > 22000 Then     'untuk Windows 11 ke atas
        Dim adjustToA4 As New Rectangle(0, 0, e.PageBounds.Width, e.PageBounds.Height)
        Dim adjustDGVtoA4 As New Rectangle(61, 300, e.PageBounds.Width - 122, e.PageBounds.Height - 860) 'adjust DataGridView

        Dim dm As New Bitmap(Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height)
        Panel1.DrawToBitmap(dm, New Rectangle(0, 0, Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height))
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(dm, adjustToA4)

        Dim dgv As New Bitmap(DataGridView1.Width, DataGridView1.Height)
        DataGridView1.DrawToBitmap(dgv, New Rectangle(0, 0, DataGridView1.Width, DataGridView1.Height))
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(dgv, adjustDGVtoA4)
    Else 'untuk Windows 10
        Dim adjustToA4 As New Rectangle(0, 0, e.PageBounds.Width, e.PageBounds.Height)
        Dim adjustDGVtoA4 As New Rectangle(5, 300, e.PageBounds.Width - 10, e.PageBounds.Height - 860)

        Dim dm As New Bitmap(Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height)
        Panel1.DrawToBitmap(dm, New Rectangle(0, 0, Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height))
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(dm, adjustToA4)

        Dim dgv As New Bitmap(DataGridView1.Width, DataGridView1.Height)
        DataGridView1.DrawToBitmap(dgv, New Rectangle(0, 0, DataGridView1.Width, DataGridView1.Height))
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(dgv, adjustDGVtoA4)
    End If

End Sub
```

I tried to do this, and it worked ok.. where the printdocument had to create two OSVersions...

so does anyone have any other suggestions...

thanks for all...